# XOR Gate using JAVA

Tags: java, xor, gate

I am trying to code an XOR Gate and I found this:

```
return in[0] != in[1];
```

where in[0] is for example true and in[1] is false. I understand that ! gives the negation but why is = used?

Comment: XOR is exclusive or -- they can't be equal. `!=` means not equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the truth table:

```
0   1   XOR
0   0   0
1   0   1
0   1   1
1   1   0
```

The example works because 0 is equal to `false` and 1 is equal to `true`
In both cases, `0 != 0` is `false` = 0, since 0 does equal 0. You can work out all other

Answer (score 2):

The operator `!=` means does not equal.

Answer (score 2):

`!=` is just the character sequence for the "not equal" operator.  xor is actually [`^` operator.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the **XOR** operator with the OR and AND operator. 
For example:

`return (in[0] | in[1]) & !(in[0] & in[1]);`